# using prop-types with useEffect and i don't know why useEffect can't identify properties of propTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm refactoring my pagination component from class to function to use react-hooks and useEffect can't read properties named Items and initialPage in variables named propTypes and defaultProps. and show this error on browser.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
(anonymous function)
src/components/Pagination.js:27
  24 | 
  25 | useEffect((prevProps) => {
  26
> 27 |   if (JSON.stringify(propTypes.items) !== JSON.stringify(prevProps.items)) {
     | ^  28 |     setPage(propTypes.initialPage);
  29 |   }
  30 | }, []);
```

Here is my codes

```
const propTypes = {
  items: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  onChangePage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  initialPage: PropTypes.number,
  pageSize: PropTypes.number,
};
const defaultProps = {
  initialPage: 1,
  pageSize: 5,
};

function Pagination(props) {
  const [pager, setPager] = useState({ pager: {} });
  useEffect(() => {
    if (propTypes.items && propTypes.items.length) {
      setPage(propTypes.initialPage);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect((prevProps) => {
    if (JSON.stringify(propTypes.items) !== JSON.stringify(prevProps.items)) {
      setPage(propTypes.initialPage);
    }
  }, []);
```

I've been stuck in this problem so hope i can get good answers or any feedbacks from here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: also the errors occur even though i changed propTypes.items to items in if (). just so you know..!!

Comment: Do you really want to check that on the prop *types*, rather than the actual *values*? Also I don't think useEffect's callback receives any arguments.

Comment: I think you meant this in the code `  if (props.items && props.items.length) {` etc.

Comment: You are not supposed to access `propTypes` during run-time at all. It's just a type checking mechanism in debug mode to warn about incorrect usage of props. What are you trying to achieve? Please explain the  problem.

Comment: @trixn **items** is the property that gets data and i've been using this to show data in orders with page numbers and stuff. But since i've changed it to useEffect from componentDidUpdate, it just doesn't work. my previous code which works alright is here `componentDidUpdate(prevProps) { if (this.props.items !== prevProps.items) { this.setPage(this.props.initialPage);}}`

Comment: @Kunukn i've tried it and it still doesn't work..

Comment: @idenhan `this.props` does no equal `propTypes`. Both class based and functional components can have `propTypes` attached but they do not contain the actual props. They are just for type checking. You likely just mean to use `props` which is the argument passed to your functional component.

Comment: @trixn Yes i've noticed that too. But, was trying everything i could think of since it just doesn't work. i changed my codes to this `useEffect((prevProps) => { if (JSON.stringify(props.items) !== JSON.stringify(prevProps.items)) { setPage(props.initialPage); }}, []);` and it shows the same error page.

Comment: @idenhan The callback of `useEffect` doesn't get the previous props passed as an argument. You should read the docs and don't make wild guesses as to how the hooks api works. Also did you make sure that the parent passes an actual array at all times to the `items` prop?

Comment: @idenhan Also your dependency array in your `useEffect` is empty which means it will only ever be called once on mount. If you want to react to prop changes the relevant props need to be in the dependencies. It looks like you did not put a lot of effort into understanding hooks first. I suggest you read the docs and do some tutorials to get comfortable with the new api before you jump into trying to guess yourself to a solution of refactoring existing class components. An answer to your question would in fact need to be a tutorial on the `useEffect` hook at that point.

Comment: @trixn right.. been on a project in a hurry so think i tried things not in a proper way. i will go back to the basic like docs and see how i can solve it. thanks for your advices much!